# Maximal increasing sequence

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sequence, sequences

i tried to make a program that finds the maximal sequence of equal elements in an array. for example:

input: *2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, **2, 2, 2**, 1*

result: *2, 2, 2*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MaximalSequence
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string previous = string.Empty;
        List<string> sequence = new List<string>();
        List<string> tempSequence = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] != previous)
            {
                tempSequence.Add(previous);
                if (tempSequence.Count > sequence.Count)
                {
                    sequence = tempSequence;
                }
                tempSequence.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                tempSequence.Add(previous);
            }
            previous = array[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sequence));
    }
}
```

the problem is that for some reason on `tempSequence.Clear();` both lists are cleared.

Comment: I am not very familiar with `C#`,  but I'd assume that `sequence` and `tempSequence` point to the same object in memory. You might need to deep copy your list, i.e. `sequence = new List<string>(tempSequence);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have pointed out, `List` is a reference type so assignment assigns by reference.  This means that both variable are changing the same underlying object (so the `.Clear` clears both lists).

The solution is to make a separate object with the same contents (aka a deep copy).  `List` provides a constructor [`public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) that copies elements from another collection (`List`).

In your code, replace `sequence = tempSequence;` with

```
sequence = new List<string>(tempSequence);
```

See this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8bH5w3)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you assign tempSequence to sequence:

```
sequence = tempSequence
```

In c# objects are passed by reference. When you clear tempSequence you clear sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`sequence = tempSequence` makes sequence the same object as tempSequence, so every change made on one of them applies to the other one, too.